# Can't see anything on Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I've just finished training a model (2000 epochs) with PyTorch Lightning. I thought PL had automatic tensorboard logging but I'm not sure. Here is the return of my training step:

```
log = {
            "total_reward": torch.tensor(self.total_reward).to(device),
            "reward": torch.tensor(reward).to(device),
            "train_loss": loss,
        }
        status = {
            "steps": torch.tensor(self.global_step).to(device),
            "total_reward": torch.tensor(self.total_reward).to(device),
        }

        return OrderedDict({"loss": loss, "log": log, "progress_bar": status})
```

Here is the structure of my lightning_logs folder :

```
.
├── version_0
│   ├── checkpoints
│   │   └── epoch=2-step=191.ckpt
│   └── hparams.yaml
├── version_1
│   ├── checkpoints
│   │   └── epoch=2-step=191.ckpt
│   └── hparams.yaml
└── version_2
    ├── checkpoints
    │   └── epoch=2-step=191.ckpt
    └── hparams.yaml

6 directories, 6 files
```

And running tensorboard :

```
tensorboard --logdir=lightning_logs
2022-02-21 19:41:13.915945: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-02-21 19:41:13.915968: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-02-21 19:41:15.602607: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-02-21 19:41:15.602639: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-02-21 19:41:15.602653: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (scrungus-pc): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
```

But when I open tensorboard I get :

`No dashboards are active for the current data set.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tensorboard logging are saved in a file with a name starting with `events.out.tfevents`, if you don't have that, then there's probably no logs.

Comment: @Ssayan what's strange is why there is no `events` file.